# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out but MySQL client can connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Seems it is a duplicate question but it is not. I have a weird problem.

I can connect to the server that MySQL runs, I can ping it, I can ssh to it. Also MySQL client can connect to the server too and I can get query results.

But if I try to connect within PHP, it gives the serror below:

```
mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out
```

Below are the other outputs:

```
root@w1 /var/www/ # mysql -h 10.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 94667239
Server version: 5.7.24-26-57-log Percona XtraDB Cluster (GPL), Release rel26, Revision 65db531, WSREP version 31.33, wsrep_31.33

Copyright (c) 2009-2019 Percona LLC and/or its affiliates
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> quit
```

Ping results:

```
root@w1 /var/www/ # ping 10.0.0.1
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.544 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.659 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.694 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.544/0.632/0.694/0.067 ms
```

Traceroute result:

```
root@w1 /var/www/ # traceroute 10.0.0.1
traceroute to 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  s1 (10.0.0.1)  0.516 ms  0.489 ms  0.442 ms
```

This is really a weird problem for me. I've also checked the MySQL host config on PHP but everything seems fine.

Any idea?

Edit:

Here is the test code:

```
root@w1 /var/www/ # more test.php 
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("10.0.0.1", "xxxxx", "yyyyyyyy", "zzz");

$test = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM test LIMIT 1");

print_r($test);
```

And the php output:

```
root@w1 /var/www/ # php test.php 
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection timed out in /var/www/test.php on line 1
PHP Notice:  Connection timed out(2002) in /var/www/test.php on line 3
```

Comment: Is your php code running in the same server as the Mysql?

Comment: Can you show the code where you do the `mysqli_connect()` along with the values (or at least a good idea of them) of the parameters used.

Comment: Show what parameters you typed inside `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: Mysql is running on a different server. This server is running for 6 months without problem. The problem starts to occur this week. There is no change on both systems and code. Mysqli connect code is:  $link = mysqli_connect($selectedDb[0], $selectedDb[1], $selectedDb[2], $selectedDb[3], $selectedDb[5]); There is 3 other servers that is running the same code for 6 months.

Comment: Kindly post your PHP code and also refer to this [ask].

Comment: Sorry, i will paste the test code to the question.

Comment: I think firewall block your server ip. so please whitelist your ip and try.

Comment: All systems are ok. There is no problem with php or mysql side. Our network techs has identified the problem. There is a packet loss on the vlan so this problem occurs. Thank you for all comments, the problem is fixed now.